# MySQL select highest score in least time

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure

```
| id | name | score | time |
----------------------------
|  1 | Mike |   120 |   35 |
|  2 | Rose |    67 |   20 |
|  3 | John |   120 |   20 |
|  4 | Kate |   130 |   50 |
```

How can I select the person who scored the highest in the least time?
Time is in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Sort by highest `score` then by lowest `time`, select 1st row:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY score DESC, `time` ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```